# How to record error messages when mapping a shared server to a network drive with VBS?

Tags: vbscript

The following snippet of script maps shared servers, stored as strings ( "\server\shared" ), in an array to the (A:) drive and record any errors encountered during the process. Then removes it to map the following item.

When some drives are mapped, depending on the user's administrative privileges, it may display an "access is denied" error message.

How can I write that message to a file in case it occurs.

```
Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

' loop through array and write shared servers to reult excel sheet 
For Each item in arrServerValues

  Echo item 
  objNetWork.MapNetworkDrive "A:", item
  ' record potential error message to a result file: Results.txt
  objNetWork.RemoveNetworkDrive "A:"  

Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about the following:

1. On Error statement: to catch the error
2. Err object: to grab the error message
3. File operations (File System Object): to write to a file